# Saddle Point Proof

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose that a real-valued function, $f$, has continuous second order partial derivatives and let $x$ be a point at which $\nabla f(x) = 0.$ Assume also that there are points $u$ and $v$ such that $\langle \nabla ^2f(x)u,u\rangle > 0$ and $\langle \nabla ^2f(x)v,v\rangle < 0$. Show that $x$ is neither a local maximum or minimum of $f$.

I'm sure that $x$ is a saddle point, but I'm unsure how to show this. Do I show that the Hessian matrix is neither positive definite nor negative definite?

Comment: This depends on what theorem you learned. In general (for $p \ge 2$), if the form $D^p f(x)(h,\dots,h)$ takes on both positive and negative values and the lower derivatives are all zero, then $x$ is not a local minimum or maximum.

Comment: Hi Dan. You're fairly new here: it might help to know that when you find an answer to be helpful, you can upvote it. And you can accept one answer per question. To accept an answer, click on the $\checkmark$ to the left of the answer you'd like to accept.

Answer (score 1):

From the given information you know that $Hf$ has at least one positive and one negative eigenvalue (it cannot be positive- or negative-semidefinite.) That is enough to show that a critical point is a saddle point, if you've learned about that result already.

Otherwise, you can also prove the statement directly. Consider the curve $\gamma(t) = x + ut$. Then $$\frac{d}{dt} f(\gamma(t)) = u\cdot \nabla f(\gamma)$$ 
and 
$$\frac{d^2}{dt^2}f(\gamma(t)) = u^T Hf(\gamma) u.$$

Since $u^THf(x)u>0$ and is continuous, there exists an $\delta > 0$ with $u^THf(\gamma[t])u>0$ for $|t| < \delta$. Then
$$u\cdot \nabla f(\gamma[t]) = u\cdot \nabla f(\gamma[t]) - u\cdot \nabla f(\gamma(0) = \int_0^t u^THf(\gamma[s])u\,ds > 0$$
for $0 < t < \delta$. And then
$$f(\gamma(t))-f(\gamma(0)) = \int_0^t u\cdot\nabla f(\gamma[s])\,ds > 0$$
for $0 < t < \delta$, and so $x$ is not a local maximum. An identical argument holds for $v$.

Answer (score 1):

All this sort of optimization relies on is Taylor's expansion. That is the workhorse.

First consider the expansion of $f$ about $x$ in the direction $u$:
\begin{align*}
  f(x + \lambda u) - f(x) & =
  \lambda \nabla f(x)^T u +
  \tfrac{1}{2} \lambda^2 u^T \nabla^2 f(x) u + o(\|\lambda u\|^2) \\ & =
  \tfrac{1}{2} \lambda^2 u^T \nabla^2 f(x) u + o(\|\lambda u\|^2)
\end{align*}
for all $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$. Choose $\lambda \neq 0$ and divide by $\lambda^2 \|u\|^2$:
$$
\frac{f(x + \lambda u) - f(x)}{\lambda^2 \|u\|^2} =
\tfrac{1}{2} \frac{u^T}{\|u\|} \nabla^2 f(x) \frac{u}{\|u\|} + o(1).
$$
Because the first term on the right-hand side is fixed and positive, the left-hand side is also positive for all sufficiently small values of $|\lambda|$, since the remainder is a term that converges to zero as $|\lambda| \to 0$. But because the denominator on the left-hand side is positive, this means that the numerator must be positive. This shows that for all sufficiently small $|\lambda| \neq 0$,
$$
 f(x + \lambda u) > f(x).
$$
Formally, there is a threshold $\lambda_{\min}$ such that for all $|\lambda| \in (0,\lambda_{\min})$, the left-hand side is larger than
$$
\mathbf{\tfrac{1}{4}} \frac{u^T}{\|u\|} \nabla^2 f(x) \frac{u}{\|u\|}
$$
(note the factor $1/4$).

Similarly, you can show that for all sufficiently small $|\lambda| \neq 0$,
$$
 f(x + \lambda v) < f(x).
$$
Therefore, any ball centered at $x$ contains points $y$ and $z$ such that $f(x) < f(y)$ and $f(x) > f(z)$, so $x$ cannot be a local minimizer. It cannot be a local maximizer either. In fact, we have proved that the definition of a saddle point is verified.